# js gulp : building a simple 2-columns page from markdowns

Tags: javascript, html, templates, markdown, gulp

I'm trying to build a "mini-book" from some markdown pages.

paths are files : docs/src/md/XYZ.md* and template : "docs/src/templates/page.txt"

the desired result would be a single page with sections, printing page-breaks after sections and 2 columns (left and right) per section.

file are freely named 0A-title0A, 0B-title0B, 1A-title1A, 1B-title1B... where the two-letters prefix (example "2A") stands for page two, "A" (left) column.

I'm a bit confused using gulp-template, gulp-order, and so on... since I have to :

1. grab markdown files in correct order
2. transform them into HTML markup
3. build a proper data object to pass to template() or swig()
4. grab the template file (lodash or swig)
5. generate in the template, the right number of sections corresponding to the number of pages (from 0 to N)

what's the quickest approach ? could I do it into one single task

regards

EDIT :

This not appears to work... the second call to 'gulp.src' seems to reset the stream and 'data0' object !

```
var docsOrdering = [
  "0A-moxicubes.md",
  "0B-moxicubes.md",
  "1A-presentation.md",
  "1B-presentation.md",
  "2A-partie.md",
  "2B-mouvements.md",
  "3A-regle-capture.md",
  "3B-regle-retournement-deplacements.md",
  "4A-scores.md",
  "4B-classements.md"
];

gulp.task("build:docs", function() {
  var data0 = { sections : [] };
  return gulp.src("src/md/*.md")
    .pipe(order(docsOrdering))
    .pipe(markdown())
    .pipe(data(function(file, cb) {
      var name = path.basename(file.path); 
      // util.log(name);
      page = name.charAt(0);
      side = name.charAt(1) === "A" ? "left" : "right";
      if(! data0.sections[page]) 
    data0.sections[page] = {};

      data0.sections[page][side] = file.contents.toString();        

      return cb(null, data0);
    }))

     // is this allowed, and have sense to grab the swig template ??
    .pipe(gulp.src("src/text/docs.html"))    
    .pipe(swig({ data : data0 } ))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("build"));

});
```

Comment: he old and crappy way : parsing md/*md into temp/*html with gulp-markdown.... then task2 with swig to generate build/docs.html, using a function to select left and right side of pages with the prefix (1A -> page1.left, 1B --> page1.right) and swig autoescape set to false !

Comment: the old and crappy way (typo)